# Spacy CLI Training Unable to Activate GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train a NER Spacy model on the CLI. Following all the steps necessary I finally created a correct input file, however when trying to train on the GPU I get the message that spacy is unable to activate the GPU, other programs actually are able to use my GPU and cuda is set up correctly. Still it doesn't seem to work, I only have 1 GPU in my computer so I selected -g 0 on the CLI. I can't find any further information as why the GPU cannot be activated, searching the internet has led to nothing either.

```
Training pipeline: ['ner']
⚠ Unable to activate GPU: 0
Using CPU only
```

- NVIDIA-driver-version: 440.64
- CUDA-verion: 10.2
- GPU GeForce RTX 2060

[Image showing the nvidia-smi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1tLu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the correct version of cupy (from your CUDA version above: `cupy-cuda102`) installed.

Comment: I checked installed packages, cupy-cuda102 is installed, as is spacy[cuda102].

Comment: Can you run `import cupy; cupy.zeros((1,))`?

Comment: Seemed to be an issue with the server, not with cupy, thanks tho!